# Binary string to unicode

Tags: string, go, byte, bin

I'm not 100% sure why my binary string to unicode isn't working..can anyone point out the issue or help me patch it? Also the reason why i chunk out the binary is that it is too large for ParseInt to handle.  See the playground link below for an example.

```
func binToString(s []byte) string {
    var counter int
    chunk := make([]byte, 7)
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    for i := range s {
        if i%8 == 0 {
            counter = 0
            if i, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(chunk), 2, 64); err == nil {
                buf.WriteString(string(i))
            }
        } else {
            chunk[counter] = s[i] //i know i can use modulus here too but i was testing and an counter was easier to track and test for me
            counter++
        }
    }
    return buf.String()
}
```

It either seems to miss a character or add an character (or two) on conversion.

Here is a [playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/M5FI8-K36M) showing an example of the function not working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function could be implemented in a simpler, more efficient manner:

```
func binToString(s []byte) string {
    output := make([]byte, len(s)/8)
    for i := 0; i < len(output); i++ {
        val, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(s[i*8:(i+1)*8]), 2, 64)
        if err == nil {
            output[i] = byte(val)
        }
    }
    return string(output)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Fmo7I-rN3c